# Cómo hacer marcos

Tags: excel, macros

Cómo hacer para crear subcarpetas si tengo una lista con nombres repetidos?
Tengo ya un código sin embargo se detiene al repetirse un nombre

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y donde esta el codigo? y que planeas hacer con los repetidos? y si solo evitas el problema controlando el error?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error **y el código como texto (nunca imagen) más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta**. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores.